# Authenticate to GCP using a Google Account, without launching a browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

#### TL;DR

Can anyone suggest a way that I can run tests as a named user that isn't a service account within a CI pipeline?

#### Detail:

We provide an application running on GCP, the stakeholders of which are all users internal to our organisation. Those users' identities are mastered in our on-premises ADFS implementation and are synced to GCP so that they can be used for authentication.
We authorize access to various parts of the application using ADFS groups that those identities can be added to and again, we sync those group memberships to GCP. The groups are available as Google Groups (https://groups.google.com). At runtime we check whether the authenticated user is a member of a given group. This all works fine.

I would like to run tests in our CI pipeline that ensure that an authenticated user can do the things they're allowed to do and can't do the things that they're not allowed to do. Here are some of the tests I would like to run:
* Ensure `gsutil ls allowed-bucket` returns an expected list of blobs
* Ensure `gsutil ls non-allowed-bucket` cannot access the named bucket
* Ensure a cloud function can be called via `gcloud functions call function-name`

Thus I need to programatically (i.e. without human intervention) authenticate as a user that is a member of a given Google group. I came up with two possibilities:

- Using a service account and authenticating using [`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /path/to/keyfile.json`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) but I cannot find a way to add a service account to the appropriate Google Group - so that option won't work
- Preparing a non-privileged user in our on-premises ADFS that we then add to the appropriate Google Group. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to authenticate as that user without human intervention because [`gcloud auth login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) uses a web-based authorization workflow. If it requires human intervention then I can't use it in a CI pipeline.

Comment: When a user authenticates with Google Accounts, access and refresh tokens are created (typically).  You can save the refresh token to generate new access tokens offline in code which are only valid for 3600 seconds. There is one potential issue. Google security monitors the use of user accounts and can block them from new devices.

Comment: Edit your question to show how you are using the user credentials - as in the actual programs. This will help me determine if it is possible to use tokens saved from user credentials.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, I have edited the question to include some example scenarios I'd like to test.

Comment: I do not know of a way to "inject" save tokens for `gsutil` as I have not tried. I did write an article on how the CLI stores credentials internally (database) and how to access them. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-where-are-my-credentials-stored/

Comment: You still might have the issue when you use user credentials on a new device where Google requires verification (sending an SMS message and entering a code). This means the whole effort might not be reliable (using user credential tokens). Your strategy of using user credentials needs to be rethought. It is not the best solution. Service accounts are.

Comment: Hi John, appreciate the responses. I don't understand your last statement though. Service accounts are not the best solution when end users need to authenticate/identify as themselves. I shall read the article you shared, thank you.

Comment: Except that automating user accounts is something that Google does not support. I wrote another article yesterday on service account impersonation with user accounts. This article shows how to save and reuse refresh tokens for user accounts using PowerShell. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/

Comment: "Except that automating user accounts is something that Google does not support." <- I guess that's the answer to my question, it isn't possible. Which is what I suspected, I just wanted someone to confirm it. We won't change our architecture (which would be a gargantuan undertaking) just to support this scenario. Instead I shall petition Google to provide a way for us to do what we need to do. Thx.

Comment: I did not say it is not possible. The security mechanism for user authentication is not public and changes. This means anything you implement might break later. You can petition Google but this won't change as they are making user authentication security harder (tighter) not easier. This is the area I work in (security, identity, etc).